# how to specify day and month but not the year in DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Hi All
I am using DateTime class to do some processing on dates. The issue I am facing is that in some cases i would like it to initialize to date component excluding the year part of date. How do i do that?
Example: For date 11/March/2011, I only want to store 11-March. How do i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't with the DateTime class (actually a struct).  You can ignore the year value in your processing, however.  You could also create your own class to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can't to that with DateTime because it is used to represent a specific moment time.
Since a day and a month are not sufficient information to represent a date, you can't store these information in DateTime only.

Maybe you should explain further what you would like to achieve.

If your concern is about outputting/formatting this date please view the following document in MSDN for format options you can apply to the toString() method of DateTime.

[MSDN: Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATETIME.GETDATETIMEFORMATS%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Something you could do if you are really forced to use DateTime is to rebase each entered date to a specific year, although I can't see how this should make any sense, especially when it comes to leap years

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to use the `TimeSpan` structure. Then you can use that on top of any `DateTime` calculations you need